# how to upload image instead of a link using apex:inputTextArea?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

Can anybody please help me to solve the issue of uploading image instead of a link in text editor. I am using apex:inputtextarea . It returns me the text editor with the option of inserting image with a link instead of uploading image. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

For uploading images shouldn't you be using [apex:inputFile](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_inputFile.htm) ?